# Classification of finite commutative rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Is there a classification of finite commutative rings available? 
If not, what are the best structure theorem that are known at present? 
All I know is a result that every finite commutative ring is a direct product of local commutative rings (this is correct, right?) in some paper which computes the size of the general linear group over that ring.

Comment: I'd guess you know this already, but Wedderburn's little theorem provides a nice dichotomy (every finite commutative ring is either a field or has zero divisors) although it's far from a complete structure theorem. 

Comment: Some progress has been made: https://doi.org/10.2140/involve.2023.16.151

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, a finite ring $R$ is a finite direct sum of local finite rings.  As a first step, for each prime $p$ there is a subring $R_p$ of $R$ corresponding to the elements annihilated by the powers of $p$. $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{R_p\ \style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{is then an}}\hspace{-7mm}}$
$\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{algebra over}}\  \mathbb{Z}/p.}$ $R_p$ then resembles an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and it could be one, but it can also have a more complicated structure as an abelian $p$-group (see below).  This step generalizes to maximal ideals:  For each maximal ideal $m$, $R_m$ is the subring of elements annihilated by $m^n$ for some $n$, and $R$ is the direct sum of these subrings, which are local rings.

It is not difficult to write down a rough partial classification of of local finite rings.  If $R$ is local with maximal ideal $m$, it <s>is</s> resembles an algebra over the finite field $F = R/m$; the associated graded ring is such an algebra.  If you choose a basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ for $m/m^2$, then $R$ or its associated graded is a quotient of the polynomial ring $F[\vec{x}]$ in which only finitely many monomials are non-zero.  You can make a diagram of these non-zero monomials; they can be any order ideal in the $n$-dimensional orthant.  Or, in basis-independent form, $R$ has a length, which is the largest nonvanishing power of $m$, and each $m^k/m^{k+1}$ is some quotient of the $k$th symmetric power of the generating vector space $V = m/m^2$.

After that, the non-zero monomials may be linearly dependent (and never mind that $R$ might be more complicated than its associated graded).  Informally, there will be an endless stream of partial results and there will never be a complete classification when the length of the local ring is 3 or more.  To see this, suppose that $m^4 = 0$, and suppose that $m^3$ is only one dimension shy of $S^3(V)$.  Then the ring is defined by an arbitrary symmetric trilinear form in $V$.  These make a "wild" sequence of algebraic varieties, in the same sense that people say that the representation theories of certain rings are wild.  For instance, I think (not quite sure) that it is NP-hard to determine when two such trilinear forms are equivalent.  NP-hardness is not by itself rigorously equivalent to no classification, but informally the classification is an intractable mess.

If the nonvanishing monomials in $R$ are linearly independent, then it is a toric local ring.  Toric local rings are certainly a tractable class of finite rings.

The situation is similar to non-commutative $p$-groups, which are also wild and will never be classified.  In both cases, certain classes have a nice structure.  It is also interesting to make estimates for how many there are.

**Note:** Corrected per comment.

Comment: These two assertions: "R_p is then an algebra over Z/p." and "If R is local with maximal ideal m, it is an algebra over the finite field F=R/m." -- are obviously wrong, as applied to finite rings, in general.  Take R = R_p = R_m = Z/p^nZ, n>1.

Comment: Oh blech, I forgot all about non-split extensions.  Thank you for that correction.


Answer (score 20):

This is a very interesting question related to the Hilbert scheme $Hilb^n(\mathbb A^d)$ classifying $n$ points in affine space $\mathbb A^d$.
I don't think there is a classification but there is an estimate for the number of commutative rings of order $\leq N$. It is

$$exp[\frac{2}{27} \frac{log(N)^3}{(log 2)^2} \; +O(log(N)^{\frac {8}{3}})]  \quad for  N\to \infty            $$

The proof of this result due to Bjorn Poonen  and of many related interesting theorems is in [his article](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/moduli.pdf)

You will also find astonishing conjectures in the article like:

The fraction of local rings of order $\leq N$ among all commutative rings $A$ of order $\leq N$
tends to 1. Same limit 1 for the fraction of rings "of characteristic 8" in the sense that $8 . 1_A =0$ but $4 .1 _A \neq 0$.

Answer (score 11):

The characterization of [Artinian rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring) is relevant of course. See also the book 
"Finite commutative rings and their applications" and [this web page](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~pcesarz/).

Answer (score 6):

As always one should check out the OEIS for questions of this type. In this case see http://oeis.org/A027623

Comment: Rather see https://oeis.org/A037289 which is specific to commutative rings.

Comment: Or even see https://oeis.org/A127707 which is specific to commutative _unital_ rings.