# Criteria for topologically finitely generated profinite groups 

Tags: topological-groups, algebraic-number-theory, gr.group-theory

Q1: Do we have a criterion which allows us to say when is a profinite group $G$ topologically finitely generated?

For example, if $G$ is topologically finitely generated then, for a fixed integer $N$,
there are only finitely many open subgroups $H\leq G$ such that $[G:H]=N$. In general, I guess that this condition is not sufficient.

Q2: Where can I find a proof that the absolute galois of $ \mathbf{Q}_p $ is topologically finitely generated?

Comment: For Q2, see Pete Clark's answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13733/wild-ramification/13743#13743 to a previous question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the theorem of Mann quoted by Jaikin in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63029/finitely-generated-galois-groups) for a nice criterion guaranteeing topological finite generation in terms of the number of open subgroups of index N.  See Pete Clark's answer to that question for pointers towards verifying that criterion for Gal(Q_p).

Answer (score 6):

The following profinite group is not finitely generated but has only finitely many open subgroups of each degree.

$$G=\prod_{n=5}^\infty (Alt_n)^{(n+1)!}.$$

Note that you need at least $n+1$ elements in order to generate $(Alt_n)^{(n+1)!}$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the bare outline of a proof that the absolute Galois group of a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is finitely generated (as a profinite group).  Let $\Omega$ be an algebraic closure of $K$, and denote groups such as $\operatorname{Gal}(\Omega|K)$ by $\Gamma(\Omega|K)$.

The profinite group $\Gamma(\Omega|K)$ has the closed normal subgroup $\Gamma(\Omega|K')$
(the ramification group --- a pro-$p$-group), where $K'$ is the maximal tamely
ramified extension of $K$ in $\Omega$, giving rise to the short exact sequence
$$
1\to\Gamma(\Omega|K')\to\Gamma(\Omega|K)\to\Gamma(K'|K)\to1.
$$
It is well known that the profinite group $\Gamma(K'|K)$ admits the
presentation
$$
\langle\sigma,\tau\mid\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}=\tau^q\rangle,
$$
where $q=p^f$ is the cardinality of the residue field $k$ of $K$
(see for example a Hasse's book or a paper by Iwasawa in the Transactions).  In view of this, it is sufficient to show that the
pro-$p$-group $\Gamma(\Omega|K')$ is finitely generated as a closed normal
subgroup of $\Gamma(\Omega|K)$.

This would follow if its abelianisation $\Delta(\Omega|K')$ were finitely
generated as a $\mathbf{Z}_p[[\Gamma(K'|K)]]$-module, which would in turn follow if
$\Delta(\Omega|K')/\Delta(\Omega|K')^p$ were finitely generated as an
$\mathbf{F}_p[[\Gamma(K'|K)]]$-module. But such is indeed the case because the
$\mathbf{F}_p[\Gamma(K'|K)]$-module $K'^\times/K'^{\times p}$ is finitely generated (by local class field theory or more simply by Kummer theory), completing the proof.

Comment: Hi @Chandan, I was wondering if you had a reference for the following statement that you made: If $\Delta(\Omega/K')$ is a finitely generated $Z_p[[\Gamma(K'/K)]]$-module then you may find finitely many elements of $\Gamma(\Omega/K')$ such that the normal closure of these elements generate it. 

Comment: @Hugo: Sorry for the belated reply; I was away for a few days.  Perhaps a more detailed account of the above outline will get written up some time soon.

Answer (score 3):

If $G_1$ has rank $r$, then all finite quotients of $G_1$ will have rank $r$.

Conversely, suppose $G$ is a profinite group such that every finite quotient has rank $\leq r$ (and some finite quotient has rank $r$). The set of finite quotients forms a lattice, since if one has epimorphisms $G\twoheadrightarrow A, G\twoheadrightarrow B$ where $A$ and $B$ are finite groups, then one has a map $G\twoheadrightarrow H\leq A\times B$, such that $G\twoheadrightarrow H\twoheadrightarrow A$ and $G\twoheadrightarrow H\twoheadrightarrow B$.

For any given finite quotient $G\twoheadrightarrow A$, consider the subset $Gen(A)\subset A^r$ consisting of $r$ elements which generate $A$. Since $A$ is finite, $Gen(A)$ is finite for all $G \twoheadrightarrow A$. By hypothesis, $Gen(A)$ is non-empty for all $G \twoheadrightarrow A$, and clearly if we have $G \twoheadrightarrow H \twoheadrightarrow A$ where $H$ is finite, then we have a map $Gen(H) \twoheadrightarrow Gen(A)$.

Thus, we may choose for all $G \twoheadrightarrow A$ an $r$-tuple $g(A)=(a_1,\ldots, a_r)\in Gen(A)$, such that if $G\twoheadrightarrow H \twoheadrightarrow A$, then $g(H)\mapsto g(A)$. This follows by the lattice property of finite quotients: we may find $G \twoheadrightarrow \cdots H_i \twoheadrightarrow \cdots \twoheadrightarrow H_2 \twoheadrightarrow H_1$ an inverse sequence of finite groups such that for any $G \twoheadrightarrow A$, there exists $i$ such that $G \twoheadrightarrow H_i \twoheadrightarrow A$. Choose $g(H_i)$ inductively so that for each $j>i$, there exists $v\in Gen(H_j)$ such that $v\mapsto g(H_i)$. Then define $g(A)=\phi(g(H_i))$ for some $i$ such that there is a factoring $G \twoheadrightarrow H_i \overset{\phi}{\twoheadrightarrow} A$. 
Now, the collection $\{ g(A), G \twoheadrightarrow A\}$ defines a unique $r$-tuple in $G$ which determines a topological generating set for $G$, since the cosets of the groups $ker\{G \twoheadrightarrow A\}$ form a neighborhood basis of $1\in G$, and therefore any nested sequence of cosets of $ker\{G \twoheadrightarrow A\}$ determines a unique element of $G$.

Thus, $rank(G)$ is the supremum of ranks of finite quotients of $G$.

Comment: Once you chose $g(H_i)$ and $j > i$, how do you define $g(H_j)$ to make sure that $g(H_j) \mapsto g(H_i)$?

Comment: @SantiagoRadi: it's a standard diagonalization/compactness argument. Each generating set of $H_j, j>i$ will map to a generating set of $H_i$. We may therefore choose a generating set of $H_i$ which is hit by infinitely many generating sets of $H_j, j>i$.

I guess that the existence of the sequence $H_i$ needs an assumption that $G$ is second countable.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not see why such a sequence would exist.